# Keeping a beverage cool

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, everyday-life, estimation

I have received a beverage in two parts: a pre-opened 200ml Coca Cola and a glass of ice.

I have the option of pouring the Coke now, when my main arrives or sometime inbetween.
I want the drink to be coolest while eating my main.

Which factors contribute the most to my decision?

Comment: The precise answer depends on a number of other factors.  What does this "glass of ice" consist of?  One big ice chunk?  A few ice cubes?  Many small ice chips?  How much ice?  What temperature is the Coke?  What temperature is the ice?

Comment: @Joshua I thought as much. Ideally, I would like to understand the physics behind this, so I can apply it to different variations of the factors you listed.

Comment: Is this an exercise purely of temperature, or is it also about concentration of soda to water (i.e. is it okay if a lot of ice melts)?  I think this is still too broad though.  Solving the transient properties of heat transfer like this will be quite involved; and we don't have enough information to even make a good estimate IMO.

Comment: @JMac I am not concerned with dilute Coke. I will edit the question.

Comment: "Which factors contribute the most to my decision?" The factor that the difference it make will be negligible to you and you waste time thinking of this instead of just drinking your coke.

Comment: @A.C.A.C. If the difference is negligible why do restaurants continue to split the glass and beverage? To prove it came from a bottle?

Comment: @Will I don't know why they do it for you where you come from but most restaurants here just gives a glass with coke and ice already in it, some will do what you said and I don't think most people ever make a big deal out of it.

Comment: @A.C.A.C. I am interested in the physics behind this. I am not seriously deliberating over such a menial question. Twice you expressed distaste in this question: downvote and move on.

Comment: This is the usual "when should I mix the two liquids" problem.  Since heat transfer is involved, somewhat more data is needed.  The ice is melting as time goes on.  How thick are the walls of the glass?  What are its dimensions?  Is the coke cooling down while this is happening?  In other words, what is the initial temperature of the coke and the air in the room?  Are there any air currents in the room?  Is the coke in a plastic container, or aluminum?  What are the dimensions of the coke container?  Etc., etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In usual conditions, pour the coke soon.

The ice will be absorbing heat from the environment all the time, and none of it will come from the coke as long as you leave it in the bottle. Besides, the temperature of the mix will be higher than that of pure ice, and a higher temperature implies less thermal exchange with the environment (as it's proportional to the temperature difference).

Now, if the glass with ice is a perfect thermal insulator, then you should mix them late: the ice will use none of its capacity to absorb heat until mixed, and the coke will always be cooled by the same amount. In this case you should wait to pour the coke until the main dish arrives, so that the mix has little time to absorb heat before being drunk.

If the glass is not a good insulator but, overall, the conductivity of the glass with pure ice is significantly smaller than that of the mix (and your dish will take long to arrive), then you should pour sometime in between.